# Can't get the build process on my Ubuntu PPA to use my debian/install file

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I'm going insane here.  I've built a tool that doesn't need any actual compilation - it's just a Perl script - and when I run `bzr builddeb` on it, I get a WORKING .deb file which copies my script - zfsync - to /usr/bin/zfsync when I run `dpkg -i zfsync_1.0.0-0ubuntu3_all.deb`.

However, when I run `bzr builddeb -S` and then `dput` the resulting source.changes file to my PPA, it builds without errors... but apt-get install zfsync results in a "successful" installation, only my binary isn't actually placed in /usr/bin!

I have a debian/install file which contains `zfsync usr/bin` and nothing else.  Out of desperation, I created a simple Makefile which, if `make install` is run, will copy zfsync to /usr/bin also.  Nothing seems to help, though, and the half-hour "build" time on Canonical's godawful arm-based PPA farm is making me lose my mind.

When I do an apt-get source zfsync, looking in the source directory fetched shows me no `debian/install` file whatsoever.  I don't know why the PPA is stripping that file, but it apparently is - and without it, my script doesn't actually get installed.

Please, please, are there any packaging gurus out there?  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why it was screwing me - I was following the Ubuntu packaging guide to the letter - but eventually I got it working.

What I ended up doing is: `apt-get source zfsync` into a completely different directory, then investigating what was in there.

In addition to a "zfsync-1.0.0" folder which contained all my stuff, there was a "zfsync" folder that had `usr/share/doc` in there but no `usr/bin` at all.  I manually created `usr/bin/zfsync` in the "zfsync" folder, made damn certain that the "debian/install" had "zfsync usr/bin" in it, then did a `bzr init`, a `bzr commit`, and a `dput ppa:jrssnet/zfsync zfsync_1.0.0-0ubuntu5_source.changes` ... and, five or ten minutes later, SUCCESS!  Ubuntu's build process actually resulted in not only a .deb, but a .deb that ACTUALLY INSTALLED MY DAMN SCRIPT. :)